# PHP JSON Array - Group by the same value

Tags: php, arrays, json, grouping

I'm thinking how to group my array by objects with the same value.

I have this result from MySQL query:

```
   Date           StartTime           EndTime
2014-12-01          08:00              12:00
2014-12-01          10:00              16:00
2014-12-02          12:00              18:00
2014-12-03          10:00              20:00
```

I have this data in a PHP variable called `$Data`.

Is it possible to get the json array like this with php: ?

```
[
    {
        "2014-12-01": [
            {
                "StartTime": "08:00",
                "EndTime": "12:00"
            },
            {
                "StartTime": "10:00",
                "EndTime": "16:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2014-12-02": [
            {
                "StartTime": "12:00",
                "EndTime": "18:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2014-12-03": [
            {
                "StartTime": "10:00",
                "EndTime": "20:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If I use `echo json_encode($Data)`, the result is:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2014-12-01",
        "StartTime": "10:00",
        "EndTime": "16:00"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-12-02",
        "StartTime": "12:00",
        "EndTime": "18:00"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-12-03",
        "StartTime": "10:00",
        "EndTime": "20:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: Sure is possible. What MySQL API are you using in your PHP code?  For most you would have to build the array while fetching, but PDO even offers [a `FETCH_GROUP` option to `fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) which would produce this structure (more or less).

Comment: I have the result from MySQL in a php variable called `$Data`.

Comment: Okay but what are the actual PHP contents of `$Data`? Please show a limited sample of it via `print_r($Data);` and also post the PHP code you used to fetch rows from MySQL into `$Data`.

Comment: The grouped output as you have posted your desired structure is kind of strange - an outer array of objects, each containing one property (date) that is an array of objects. It would make more sense to have an outer object with keys (dates) each an array of objects. 2 fewer levels of nesting.

Comment: Like `{"2014-12-01": [{"StartTime": "10:00", "EndTime":"16:00"},{"StartTime": "10:00","EndTime": "16:00"}],"2014-12-02":[{"StartTime":"12:00","EndTime":"18:00"}]`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yep, like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the structure outlined in the question:

Requires php 5.4+ for the json pretty printing, if you are on a lower version just remove it and use long array format.

```
$in = <<<'JSON'
[
    {
        "Date": "2014-12-01",
        "StartTime": "10:00",
        "EndTime": "16:00"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-12-02",
        "StartTime": "12:00",
        "EndTime": "18:00"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-12-03",
        "StartTime": "10:00",
        "EndTime": "20:00"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-12-03",
        "StartTime": "12:00",
        "EndTime": "20:00"
    }
]
JSON;

$data = json_decode($in, true);
$out = [];

foreach($data as $element) {
        $out[$element['Date']][] = ['StartTime' => $element['StartTime'], 'EndTime' => $element['EndTime']];
}

var_dump(json_encode($out, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

To get the exact same output as in the question (the returned output wrapped in a single element json-array you'd need to wrap `$out` in an other array like this:

`json_encode([$out], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`

Results in:

```
{
  "2014-12-01": [
    {
      "StartTime": "10:00",
      "EndTime": "16:00"
    }
  ],
  "2014-12-02": [
    {
      "StartTime": "12:00",
      "EndTime": "18:00"
    }
  ],
  "2014-12-03": [
    {
      "StartTime": "10:00",
      "EndTime": "20:00"
    },
    {
      "StartTime": "12:00",
      "EndTime": "20:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EMPLOYER NAME DATA_PATH
Alp             1. video_link
                2. video_link
Xyz             1. video_link
                2. video_link
                3. video_link

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT a.employer_name,b.data_path FROM 
rec_experience a INNER JOIN rec_multi_upload_data b 
ON(a.rec_uniqueid=b.rec_id) WHERE b.data_type='Video'  ORDER BY 
a.c_date DESC ");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$out = [];

foreach($res as $element)
{
 $out[$element['employer_name']][] = ['video_link' => 
 $element['data_path']];
}
echo json_encode($out);
```