# Ajax success jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

```
[{ 
    "SchoolId": "015-08-0034-009-37",
    "SubjectId": "08-0034-00613",
    "StudentId": "T-15981",
    "StudentName": "John"
},{
    "SchoolId": "015-08-0034-009-37",
    "SubjectId": "08-0034-00613",
    "StudentId": "T-15982",
    "StudentName": "Paul"
}]
```

This is the json_encode response from my php page when i do echo if would look like this

```
Schoolid=015-08-0034-009-37
Subjectid=08-0034-00613
Studentid=T-15981
Studentname=John
Schoolid=015-08-0034-009-37
Subjectid=08-0034-00613
Studentid=T-15982
Studentname=Paul
```

I can get this result by doing like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].schoolid);
    console.log(data[i].subjectid);
    console.log(data[i].studentid);
    console.log(data[i].studentname);
}
```

How can i make it in a way that the value of same entry will be generated only once like the value of `school id` and `subject id` will be shown only once the unique value like `student id` and `student name` will be shown twice since there are two different values for it.

I am hoping to get the result as

```
Schoolid=015-08-0034-009-37
Subjectid=08-0034-00613

Studentid=T-15981
Studentname=John
Studentid=T-15982
Studentname=Paul
```

Where should i do the fixing for this one in php before passing the json_encode or in ajax after receiving the json_encode from php?

```
if ($stmt - > rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $basicinfo[] = array('schoolid' => $selected_row['schoolid'], 'subjectid' => $selected_row['subjectid'], 'studentid' => $selected_row['studentid'], 'studentname' => $selected_row['studentname']);
        //$basicinfo1[] = array('schoolid' => $selected_row['schoolid'], 'subjectid' => $selected_row['subjectid']);
        //$basicinfo2[] = array('studentid' => $selected_row['studentid'], 'studentname' => $selected_row['studentname']);
    }
    //$merge = array_merge($basicinfo1 , $basicinfo2);
    //$add = $basicinfo1 + $basicinfo2)
    //$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $merge)));
    $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $basicinfo)));
    echo json_encode($input, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Comment: If you are not doing anything other than displaying the values then it is better you make the change in PHP

Comment: @Lepanto i am putting that value in input box so yeah just displaying how? i tried `merge array` and `+ array` but i am not getting the correct response

Comment: i left what i tried as comment..

Comment: I know what you mean, you want to sort of group your data. Well you should fix your php. I dont know if there is any php scripts that can do that. There are some problems with that idea. You should tell the script how you want your data to be joined, because you could join wrong data.

How everyone else does this? Well I think they usually construct data with more queries.

Comment: @luka so there are no other option but to the fixing in the quries..thanks for the idea

Comment: Not that i know of, at least there is no generic way. You could do loops like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327881/php-json-array-group-by-the-same-value

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help you fix the array in PHP

```
if ($stmt - > rowCount() > 0) {
    //$new_data = array();
    while ($v = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $tmp_key = $v['SchoolId'].'-'.$v['SubjectId']; //adding a temp key

        $new_data[$tmp_key]['SchoolId'] = $v['SchoolId'];
        $new_data[$tmp_key]['SubjectId'] = $v['SubjectId'];

        $sudky = (isset($new_data[$tmp_key]['Student'])) ? count($new_data[$tmp_key]['Student']) : 0; //getting the key for student child array
        $new_data[$tmp_key]['Student'][$sudky]['StudentId'] = $v['StudentId'];
        $new_data[$tmp_key]['Student'][$sudky]['StudentName'] = $v['StudentName'];
    }
    $new_data = array_values($new_data);
    echo json_encode($new_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

The final JSON data will be like following

```
[{
    "SchoolId":"015-08-0034-009-37",
    "SubjectId":"08-0034-00613",
    "Student":[
        {"StudentId":"T-15981","StudentName":"John"},
        {"StudentId":"T-15982","StudentName":"Paul"}
    ]
}]
```

In Javascript you will have to add another loop inside the `for` loop you alreardy have that goes through `Student` data

Following is the Javascript section

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "YOURSCRIPT",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            if(data!=''){
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    alert(data[i].SchoolId);
                    alert(data[i].SubjectId);
                    var student = data[i].Student;
                    for (var j = 0; j < student.length; j++) {
                        alert(student[j].StudentId);
                        alert(student[j].StudentName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Im getting undefined index in `Student` in `$sudky = count($new_data[$tmp_key]['Student']); //getting the key for student child array` where is this `Student` from

Comment: also i have this warning `You should use only:
1 assignment(s) (2 used)
to a variable:` in line `$new_data = array();`

Comment: cool i can get the result youre displaying but i am having problems showing it in jquery can you show me how to get the value of student id. from success i get value of other data like this `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     console.log(data.[i].SchoolId);
     console.log(data.[i].SubjectId);
}` how to get the studentname?

Comment: I have added the javascript jquery code as well, check it

Comment: Sir i am having dup value how can i delete dup values. Example 8 student id?

Comment: what is the `tmp_key ` for example this one `$tmp_key = $v['SchoolId'].'-'.$v['SubjectId'];`

Comment: please clarify on how the multidimensional array was created

Comment: I am having duplicate entry move like it is looping through the same entry over and over again..in my database i have only 2 entry but when i tried your code i am getting 6 as result. I am guessing it has something to do with the `$tmp_key`